# How is the split function in perl supposed to work?

Tags: regex, perl, split

I was having some difficulty with the split function today, and read through the [perlfunc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html)
to see if I had interpreted something incorrectly.  I was attempting to split a string on '.', which according to the perlfunc should be supported thusly:

```
my $string = "hello.world";
my ($hello, $world) = split(".", $string);
```

or

```
my $string = "hello.world";
my ($hello, $world) = split(/\./, $string);
```

However, testing the first resulted in empty variables, so I extended my testing to the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $time_of_test = "13.11.19.11.45.07";
print "TOD: $time_of_test\n";
my ($year, $month, $day, $hr, $min, $sec) = split(/\./, $time_of_test);
print "Test 1 -- Year: $year month: $month day: $day hour: $hr min: $min sec: $sec\n";
($year, $month, $day, $hr, $min, $sec) = split(".", $time_of_test);
print "Test 2 -- Year: $year month: $month day: $day hour: $hr min: $min sec: $sec\n";
($year, $month, $day, $hr, $min, $sec) = split('.', $time_of_test);
print "Test 3 -- Year: $year month: $month day: $day hour: $hr min: $min sec: $sec\n";
($year, $month, $day, $hr, $min, $sec) = split("\.", $time_of_test);
print "Test 4 -- Year: $year month: $month day: $day hour: $hr min: $min sec: $sec\n";
($year, $month, $day, $hr, $min, $sec) = split('\.', $time_of_test);
print "Test 5 -- Year: $year month: $month day: $day hour: $hr min: $min sec: $sec\n";
```

Here is the output:

```
> ./test.pl  
TOD: 13.11.19.11.45.07
Test 1 -- Year: 13 month: 11 day: 19 hour: 11 min: 45 sec: 07
Test 2 -- Year:  month:  day:  hour:  min:  sec: 
Test 3 -- Year:  month:  day:  hour:  min:  sec: 
Test 4 -- Year:  month:  day:  hour:  min:  sec: 
Test 5 -- Year: 13 month: 11 day: 19 hour: 11 min: 45 sec: 07
```

Is this working as intended?  If so, how did I misinterpret the perlfunc documentation?

Comment: +1 This confirmed my suspicion that split always interpolates the first argument as a regular expression.

Comment: When in doubt, check perldoc => http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html

Comment: If you weren't getting Perl complaining about bare words in `my $string = hello.world;`, you weren't running with `use strict;` and `use warnings;`, which is … careless? dangerous? silly?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - You are correct, and this was careless on my part.  I intended for this bit of information to be pseudocode.. The real code that I tested with is the large chunk starting with the she-bang line.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I have updated the question to correct the bare words.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first argument to split is a regular expression. You should never use a string here (except in the special case of `" "`), because it's misleading as to the actual behavior.

The reason you got no results when splitting with `"."` and `'.'` is that it was interpreting these as regular expressions (split on *everything*).

With `/\./` and `'\.'` you got the expected results, because the dot was correctly escaped in the regular expression.

You didn't get any results for `"\."` because it was treated as an escape sequence by the double-quoted string first, before being treated as a regular expression by `split`. By the time this made it to the `split` call, it was the same as `"."`.

Comment: "" isn't a special case, it is treated just like //

Comment: @ysth You are right, it's not a special case as far as functionality goes, but more in terms of readability. I'd consider it as a case where using a string instead of a regexp is acceptable.

Answer (score 4):

The string literal `'\n'` produces the string `\n`. The string literal `'.'` produces the string `.`. That string expected to be a regular expression. `.` in a regular expression matches any character except newline. The regular expression `\.` would match a period, and that string can be created from string literal `'\.'` or `'\\.'`. It's less misleading and simpler to escape most patterns if you use `/\./`, though.

Answer (score 0):

First parameter in split function is a regular expression.
In regular expression '.' means 'any character'. If you want to split at dot, use /\./ by escaping '.'

Comment: Is it always a regular expression regardless of how it is called?  By that, I mean wouldn't '\.' and "\." be the same regex?  Or, is "\." interpolated as the string \. in regex?

Comment: Yes! First argument is a regular expression. Also note that strings and regular expressions are different in perl. Unlike in java or C# perl regular expressions are first class literals.

Comment: @Bts, It's always a regex. `'\.'` produces the string `\.`, and `"\."` produces the string `.`, so they're not the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split on a `.` using a string, you have to escape it twice:

```
my $string = 'hello.world';
my ($hello, $world) = split('\\.', $string);
print "$hello\n";
```

That outputs "hello".

If you only pass in `'\.'`, that will end up as just a wildcard `'.'` in the split function. You need two backslashes, so that it ends up as a `'\.'` getting passed to the split function.

Comment: since single quotes treat backslashes as literals unless doubled or precede the string delimiter, '\.' in fact does work (though "\." does not).  but to show the reader that it is in fact a regex, better to just use /\./